# Utility of Topological Data Analysis in Theoretical Physics

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, soft-question, data-analysis, algebraic-topology

I audited a lecture on [Topological Data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_data_analysis), and I found it really interesting, primarily because of the connection to algebraic topology. I asked the professor if there are any connections to (theoretical) physics, and he told me that indeed there are, and that he intents to bring a cosmologist to give a relevant presentation. The professor is from the Mathematics department so he doesn't know more details. I also searched online and I could find only a few mentions about the utility of TDA in string theory and swampland.

I know the name gives it away, it's a tool for analysing data, but I would like to know if there is any utility for a theoretical physicist, for example if it offers any further intuitions, if the methods used in it are useful broadly etc. I know many string theorists have gotten into machine learning and its applications in string theory so I was wondering if it's something with similar utility.

EDIT: Now that I have seen more about the mathematical methods and tools backing topological data analysis, I feel like I could make my question a little bit more specific. Is persistence theory (persistent homology/cohomology) useful for theoretical physics? Do you know of any work using it/ or that could use it to arrive at the same result?

Comment: I think there's been some work applying these techniques to cosmology (e.g. [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/465/4/4281/2453824)). I don't see how it would be very useful for string phenomenology. It's just one of many data analysis techniques.

Comment: @knzhou To be honest I haven't seen enough about string theory yet, but I know that vacuum states pose a problem. A relevant article for string theory vacua and TDA is the [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/JHEP03%282019%29054.pdf).

Comment: Wild guess: It's useul for sorting experimental data and recreating moedls out of them